# passing null to DBtype.binary

Tags: c#, sql-server, ado.net

I am using sqlparameter to insert value in to the table through procedure 
i have a prameter in procedure of type image 
in c# i set the parameter type as DbType.Binary
now i want to pass Null value to the parameter if i use DBNull.value, i get incompatible data type error

Comment: What happens if you set it to a CLR null?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try like this int the sp set parametar default value null like this @parametar  Binary = NULL
and then in the code test if the value is null and if it is null just don't pass parameter to the sp and it will take default value null.